# How to add labels to flow lines in modelio?

Tags: modelio

[image: https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/pages/chart/bpmn/gateways/exclusive-gateway-example-420x201.jpg]

Like in the picture above (Land and Sea), how to add labels to flow lines in Modelio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *"Symbol"* tab, you have to check the *"Show label"* property but in UML I would say that are not the label of the flows but their guards...

Comment: There is no "Show label" property in my symbol tab, but there's "Show guard", setting the guard text also works as label, thanks.

Comment: Which formalism do you use ? BPMN or UML activities?

Comment: In this case, in the "Element" tab use the guard field. Its value will be layouted in the diagram.